# How to remove string after end of file extension

Tags: powershell, scripting, file-rename, microsoft-file-explorer

I have a few hundred files in file explorer that I am looking to rename.
All of the files end with a set of 2 characters after the extension. EX: `23RH1.JPG;1`
Is there a way to batch rename all of the files by removing the last 2 characters from all of the file names? Or maybe a Powershell script I could run that would auto remove last 2 characters from end of all the file names?

Thank You in advance

so far i have tried running something along the lines of

```
get-childitem *.JPG | rename-item -newname { $_.fullname.substring(0,$_.fullname.length-2) + $_.extension }
```

and

```
gci <dir path \*> |% {rename-item $_.fullname -newname $_.basename -whatif}
```

Unfortunately my PowerShell knowledge is quite limited and I'm not really sure how to mass rename a ton of files at once as its a fairly new tool to me.

Huge thank you to anyone that could offer any help or advice.

Comment: If that's a one time task you may use a batch file rename tool like PowerToys [PowerRename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/powerrename).

Comment: What would happen if there are files with the correct extension? Do all files end with `;1` ? If so, you could use the filter to refine your search

Comment: all files end in either a ";1" ";2" or ";3"

Comment: Idle curiosity:  do these files come froma Files-11 environment?

Answer (score 2):

In this case the recommendation would be to refine your filter to **find only those files ending with `.jpg` followed by `;` and anything after**, then for renaming, you could use a simple regex that replaces the last 2 characters from a string `.{2}$`:

```
Get-ChildItem path\to\targetfolder -Filter '*.jpg;?' |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.{2}$' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot

`Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Path\To\Your\Folder" | foreach {Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ($_.BaseName.Substring(0, $_.BaseName.Length - 2) + $_.Extension)}`